# Groups of certain order

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $2^aq^b$ for odd prime $q$ and $a,b\geq 2$. Suppose $G$ has at least $2$ subgroups $A$ and $B$ of order $2^{a}$. 
I suspect that $A\cap B$ is a normal subgroup of size $2^{a-1}$. Any hint to the proof or give a counter example if you don't believe the proposition is true.

**This question is answered with a counter example below.**

Comment: Well, the edited question seems to be sounder, but: why do you *suspect* $\;A\cap B\;$ is (1) normal, and also (2) of size $\;2^{a-1}\;$ ? This seems to be a lot to suspect if there's no more information.

Comment: Anyway, that's what I want to apply it in my proof. But couldn't get a counter example why that doesn't hold, and couldn't come up with a proof either.

Comment: I assume you're excluding the case $A = B$?

Comment: Yes, that's why I said at least two subgroups $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @SteamyRoot Obviously, otherwise $\;|A\cap B|=2^a\;$ ...

Answer (score 2):

**Counterexample:**
Let $S_3$ be the symmetry group on $[1,3]$.
Let $G=S_3\times S_3$. $|G|=2^23^2$.
Let $\tau_1 = (1,2) \in S_3$ and $\tau_2 = (1,3) \in S_3$
Let $A$ be the subgroup generated by $(\tau_1,e)$ and $(e,\tau_1)$
Similarly let $B=\langle (\tau_2,e) , (e,\tau_2) \rangle$.
Then $A \cap B=\{e\}$.

This example can be extended to make $|A\cap B|=2^k$ for any $0 \leq k < a$.